# Spark RDD operation summing the values by keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark RDD like below:
RDD[string] that has values like:

```
(00,"asfad", 12)
(01,"fdfdf", 14)
(02,"fdfsfdg",232)
(00, "asfad", 34)
(01, "fdfdf", 12)
```

Now I want something like this:

```
 (00,"asfad",46)
 (01, "fdfdf",26)
 (02, "fdfsfdg",232)
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this using scala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have something like that RDD[(Int, String, Int)] then you can try this

```
rdd.map { case (a, b, c) => ((a, b), c) }.reduceByKey((x, y) => x + y).map { case ((a, b), c) => (a, b, c) }
```